# Присвоить String переменной значение JSTL переменной

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Здравствуйте. Создаю переменную :

```
<c:set var="editId" value="${cell.id}"></c:set>
```

Как мне присвоить переменной String s значение переменной editId . 
Вот так не получается : `<% String s = ${editId} %>`

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

```
<% String s= pageContext.getAttribute("editId"); %>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.